# python if statement usageApython variable assignment

Tags: python-3.x

```
pass=45

if pass==35:
    print ("just pass")
else pass<35:
    print ("fail")
else:
    print("passed with distinction")
```

error:

```
 File "<ipython-input-6-5b2b900f3e01>", line 1
    pass="45"
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax   |
```

Comment: `pass` is a keyword, so you can't use it as a variable name.  Change the name to something else.

Answer (score 0):

pass is reserved keyword in python, reference : https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/keyword-list

Use _pass or some other variable name

```
 _pass=45
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer

Answer (score 0):

Should not repeat `else` in a single `if .. else` block. Use `if .. elif .. else` instead. And DONOT use reserved keywords as variables. Here is the list of reserved keywords that must be avoided as variable/function name https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/keywords-identifier

```
mypass = 45

if mypass == 35:
    print ("just pass")
elif mypass < 35:
    print ("fail")
else:
    print("passed with distinction")
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should never use reserved keywords as variable names, irrespective of the language you code in. `pass` is a reserved keyword in Python, see this link - [Python Documentation for pass](https://docs.python.org/3.2/reference/simple_stmts.html#pass).

Secondly, the correct syntax for if-else is as follows:

```
if condition_1:
    do_something
elif condition_2:
    do_something_else
else:
    do_some_other_thing
```

You're supposed to use the `elif` keyword for secondary blocks. So the correct code is:

```
my_variable = 45    
if my_variable == 35:
     print("just pass")
elif my_variable < 35:
     print("fail")
else:
     print("passed with distiction")
```

Hope that helps.